# Retrieving data from Firebase using .data by the name of fields inside StreamBuilder flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream-builder

`So I m trying to retrieve data from my firebase collection using field names...I am following tutorials..But I am struck here..Since following the same way as shown in tutorials..But my code is getting error..I think maybe .data[] has been modified..But couldn't find a way of doing the same task.
Here's my code and firebase database SS.My first question here..Sorry if not being up to mark.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm7vb.png)

```
final messages=snapshot.data.docs;
for(var message in messages)
{final messageText= message.data['text'];
final messageSender= message.data['sender'];}``
```

`

[Firebase Database field names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWlPF.png)

Comment: That extra .data after .message looks troublesome.  Have you tried it just as `message['text']`?  Can you print(message) and see what it dumps as?

Comment: I tried with message['text'] and it worked..Thanks a lot.